# C++ char hex value to byte

Tags: c++, hex

I have a hex value in a char pointer (for example 'F3'), and I would like to convert it to byte, because I want it to put in an array. I know that there are many solutions, but they are not what I wanted.

Thanks in advance!

EDIT:

Okay, maybe I have not written everything.
What I have now:

```
char aChar[5];
itoa (j, aChar, 16);
```

j is now 3, and I just want it in byte. Atoi, scanf doesn't help, those are the different solutions.

Comment: you should post what you tried, and why it doesn't work for you...

Comment: "I know that there are many solutions, but they are not what I wanted." What was wrong with them? Why would I write a solution to be told: "that's not what I wanted!"

Comment: Okey, I have tried scanf, atoi, but the result is always 0, and printf doesn't show anything. I have a char, with itoa it is now in hex and I would like to convert it to byte.

Comment: ...and yet I do, I must be mad. I presume `hex2byte("f3") == 243` is what is required. It's hard to tell what is meant by "byte" here. Perhaps "11110011"?

Answer (score 7):

Since you've tagged this C++ and not C, I'm not going to use any C functions (except `assert()` to demonstrate the behaviour, edge conditions, *et cetera*). Here's a sample file. Let's call it hex2byte.cpp:

```
#include <sstream>
#include <cassert>

unsigned char hex2byte(const char* hex)
{
    unsigned short byte = 0;
    std::istringstream iss(hex);
    iss >> std::hex >> byte;
    return byte % 0x100;
}

int main()
{
    const char* hex = "F3";
    assert(hex2byte(hex) == 243);
    assert(hex2byte("") == 0);
    assert(hex2byte("00") == 0);
    assert(hex2byte("A") == 10);
    assert(hex2byte("0A") == 10);
    assert(hex2byte("FF") == 255);
    assert(hex2byte("EEFF") == 255);
    assert(hex2byte("GG") == 00);
    assert(hex2byte("a") == 10);
    assert(hex2byte("0a") == 10);
    assert(hex2byte("f3") == 243);
    assert(hex2byte("ff") == 255);
    assert(hex2byte("eeff") == 255);
    assert(hex2byte("gg") == 00);
}
```

Make it:

```
% make hex2byte
g++ -Wall -Wextra -Wshadow -pedantic -Weffc++ -Werror hex2byte.cpp -o hex2byte
```

Run it:

```
% ./hex2byte
```

No assertions. Add error handling to taste (such as checking for when `hex == NULL`, *et cetera*).

Answer (score 3):

A byte is usually simply an unsigned char

```
myArray[n] = (unsigned char)*p;
```

Or do you mean that you have a string representation of an hex value?

Answer (score 1):

Given a `char *` with `"F3"`:

```
char *hexstr = "F3";
```

Then you can do this:

```
unsigned char byteval =
    (((hexstr[0] >= 'A' && hexstr[0] <= 'Z') ? (10 + hexstr[0] - 'A') : 
    (hexstr[0] >= 'a' && hexstr[0] <= 'z') ? (10 + hexstr[0] - 'a') : 
    (hexstr[0] >= '0' && hexstr[0] <= '9') ? (hexstr[0] - '0') : 0) << 4) |
    ((hexstr[1] >= 'A' && hexstr[1] <= 'Z') ? (10 + hexstr[1] - 'A') : 
    (hexstr[1] >= 'a' && hexstr[1] <= 'z') ? (10 + hexstr[1] - 'a') : 
    (hexstr[1] >= '0' && hexstr[1] <= '9') ? (hexstr[1] - '0') : 0);
```

I'm sorry for its ugliness; I'm sure it can be improved.

You can turn this into a function:

```
inline unsigned char hextobyte(const char *s) {
    return
    (((s[0] >= 'A' && s[0] <= 'Z') ? (10 + s[0] - 'A') : 
    (s[0] >= 'a' && s[0] <= 'z') ? (10 + s[0] - 'a') : 
    (s[0] >= '0' && s[0] <= '9') ? (s[0] - '0') : 0) << 4) |
    ((s[1] >= 'A' && s[1] <= 'Z') ? (10 + s[1] - 'A') : 
    (s[1] >= 'a' && s[1] <= 'z') ? (10 + s[1] - 'a') : 
    (s[1] >= '0' && s[1] <= '9') ? (s[1] - '0') : 0);
}
```

Comment: Uh, o r you know `unsigned char x; sscanf(s, "%hhx", &x);` :)

Comment: That's pretty cool, I didn't know that there even was a `%hhx` format specifier for `scanf`. In my solution's defence, I believe that it may be able to run faster than the `sscanf` approach.

Comment: @Delan: With all those conditionals in the code I doubt it. I think the scanf version will be optimized to work very quickly.

Answer (score 1):

I can think of at least five ways:

1. using `sscanf` with `%x`
2. using `strtol` with the correct base
3. using `istringstream` (though you'll have to down cast from unsigned short to unsigned char)
4. boost::spirit
5. hand rolled loop to parse character-by-character

None of the ways you listed would work. But your question still isn't really clear, you have a char which somehow you converted to hex using `itoa` and now you want to convert to a byte!?! what's wrong with a cast? e.g. `unsigned char byte = static_cast<unsigned char>(charvalue);`